# How can I get "Bar" from "Foo::Bar" in rust macro?

Tags: rust, macros, dst, rust-macros

Original demand: I want to implement a macro that converts `Foo::*` to `Bar::*`.

Pseudo code will look like this:

```
macro_rules! convert_foo_to_bar {
    ($v: ty, $p: path) => (<$v>::$p.name)
}

// convert_foo_to_bar!(Bar, Foo::A) -> Bar::A
```

While `$p.name` refers to `A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match the `Foo::A` using `Foo::$variant:ident` to get `A` as `$variant` like this:

```rust
macro_rules! convert_foo_to_bar {
    ($v: ty, Foo::$variant:ident) => (<$v>::$variant)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0fecc2cabbb9cb8e6242825fef3025b9)

If you need to convert a variable, you will need to use a normal function such as this:

```rust
fn convert_foo_to_bar(foo: Foo) -> Bar {
  match foo {
    Foo::A => Bar::A,
    Foo::B => Bar::B,
    // .. for all of your variants
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried your solution, but now I have one more question: if I have `let a = Foo::A`, how to deal with `convert_foo_to_bar!(Bar, a)` ?

Comment: @JasonSui I don't think a macro would be able to get information about what variant a variable `a` is, so you'd use a function, see the update on my answer.

Comment: If instead of `Bar`, you need another type, you could create a new function, with the same match, or instead, put the match inside of a macro, replacing `Bar::` with `<$v>::`, just like in your original macro.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Maybe I should get a further understand about the Rust Macro.